# Clearing Only inner text and not the childnodes

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml as below

```
< Image>ImageValue1
  <Type>png</Type>
  <Value>ImageValue1</ Value>
</ Image>
```

Here ImageValue1 is present in two places.I want to remove innerText for Image node which is the parent.For which I am using the below code

```
XmlNode customImageNode = imagedoc.SelectSingleNode("//Image");
customImageNode.InnerText = string.empty;
```

But this is clearing the child nodes as well.Please let me know how to clear this test off .Looking for a generic solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you need to do is select just the *text* node of the `Image` node. You do this like this:

```
XmlNode customImageNodeTextNode = imageDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Image/text()");
customImageNodeTextNode.InnerText = string.Empty;
```

I just tested the above code and it worked for me. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

try doing:
 `customImageNode.Value= string.empty;`

update:
sorry for the mistake. It's supposed to be like so: `customImageNode.RemoveChild(customImageNode.FirstChild);`, since the inner text of the node is it's first child in this case. I've checked it and it works.

Comment: I think Dan's answer looks cleaner.Anyway thanks a lot for the help RA